Building a minimal jar in Eclipse
I'm building a small java project in Eclipse and exporting a runnable jar with package library handling. The jar runs fine. The program needs an HSQLDB JDBC driver so the requisite jar is packaged. This jar drags the entire  embedded database server into my jar which is unnecessary as I use the standalone server. Is there an easy way to limit my jar size to contain only my project and the jdbc driver?
I replaced the HSQLDB jar dependency with a reference to the external HSQLDB class library. No luck; the ubiquitous "no suitable driver" exception is thrown.

In HSQLDB parlance the standalone server is  a separate executable intended for client/server applications.  Thus the client only needs a jdbc driver.

The jar HSQLDB contains both the server and the client. There is no separate jar for the client.
You can build a smaller jar, hsqldbmin, using the Gradle build. See https://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/building-app.html
